# Как избежать кеширования в браузере PDF при открытии по ссылке?

Tags: html, кэширование, pdf, браузер, ссылка

На сайте есть ссылка на документ pdf вида:

```
<a href="programma.pdf">Программа мероприятия</a>
```

При обновлении документа в браузере всё равно открывается старая версия (нужно каждый раз чистить кеш, чтобы открылся новый документ).

Менять название нельзя: ссылка на программу ушла в e-mail-рассылке многим подписчикам именно в таком виде.

Как можно избежать кеширования pdf, чтобы всегда открывалась актуальная версия документа?

Comment: <a href="programma.pdf?v=1234">Программа мероприятия</a> версию добавляйте

Comment: @Konst, я не уточнил: название документа нельзя менять, потому что ссылка на него ушла в e-mail рассылке. Соответственно добавить в ссылку версию не получится

Comment: Если народ уже успел посетить ссылку, то никак, уже закешировалось условно навсегда. Если не успел, то прописать соответствующий Cache-Control в HTTP-заголовках

Comment: @andreymal, а соответствующий - это какой? Можете пример привести?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/Cache-Control

Answer (score 0):

Под ссылку в рекламе можно поставить не сам файл, а страничку со скриптом, который перебрасывает на него.
В коде можно менять версию файла.
Например, задавая её функцией time() в php.
Тогда при каждом новом обращении она будет заведомо свежее сохранённой в кэше.

Вот пример такого скрипта:

```
<?php
    $new_url = 'URLфайла?v='.time();
    header('Location: '.$new_url);
    ?>
```

Замечу, что html-перенаправление метатегом "Refresh" использовать не стоит, так как страница с ним тоже может быть закэширована, и версия в ней всегда будет совпадать с версией файла в кэше.

Comment: Некропостер, ты хоть комментарии почитай